# angular1.x currency filter w/ no zero

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement to not render a currency value if it is zero.

i.e.:

```
v=1 render $1
v=0 render nothing
```

[ EDIT ]

**:egg on face:**

Once I looked deeper into the core code, I found there **is** a custom filter.

```
angular
    .module('com.td.tdct.bbpcCore')
    .filter('currencyFilter', ['$rootScope', 'tdBbpcUserService', '$filter', function ($rootScope, tdBbpcUserService, $filter) {
    return function (input, decimal, symbol) {
        var languageCd;

        if (input) {
            if (!$rootScope.languageChange) {
                languageCd = tdBbpcUserService.getLanguageCd();
            } else {
                languageCd = $rootScope.languageChange;
            }

            var value = input.toString().replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            value = (angular.isNumber(decimal)) ? $filter('number')(value, decimal) : $filter('number')(value);

            if (angular.isString(languageCd) && (languageCd.toUpperCase() === "FR" || languageCd.toUpperCase() === "FR_CA")) {
                value = (angular.isDefined(symbol) && symbol === "N") ? value.toString() : value.toString() + "  $";
            } else {
                value = (angular.isDefined(symbol) && symbol === "N") ? value.toString() : "$  " + value.toString();
            }
            return value;
        }

    };
}]);
```

It's implemented thus:

```
{{asset.prevMarginalRate | currencyFilter:0}}
```

I'd like to either

- add an **optional** flag to this existing filter - to return empty if set (it's got to be optional, since existing methods that use this shouldn't be affected)

or

- layer another filter on top.

whichever is best practice.

In the first case, I'm trying to figure out how to pass that flag in, sort of thus:

```
{{asset.prevMarginalRate | currencyFilter:0, true}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own filter for achieve this.

I would do something like this:

```
app.filter('currencyWithoutZero', function() {
    return function(x) {
      if(x !== 0) return '$' + x;
      else return '';
    };
});
```

**[Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QTq344eHfuxxGOcRiFer?p=preview)**

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

`0` is *falsy*. So you can do an OR operation to remove if like any `false` / `null` / empty values.

```js
function foo(x) {
  return x || "nothing";
}

v = 1;
console.log(foo(v));
v = 0;
console.log(foo(v));
```

Comment: Updated question. :awkward:

Comment: @DaveC426913 ouch, yeah I think you need to extend your `value`, try something like `value = value ? ((angular.isDefined(symbol) && symbol === "N") ? value.toString() : "$  " + value.toString()) : "";`

Comment: ^ in short: `v = v ? (/* truthy */) : "" /* falsy */`. Once again, `0` is falsy, so it will select empty string instead of that giant formatting filter